# Custom Major Mode - Regex to find word before equal sign and set font-lock-variable-name-face

Tags: faces, regular-expressions

I'm trying to create my own major mode. So far I've been able to set all the syntax highlighting that I need, but I'm struggling with this one.

Basically I need to color any word before an equal sign. Like this:

< action **name=**"set_button">

Like the face nxml-attribute-local-name in nxml-mode.

To do this I'm using a regular expression to find that word and then set font-lock-variable-name-face.

I've tried the following regular expressions, but they didn't work. I don't know if it's because I'm not escaping them correctly or because emacs doesn't support them.

```
 ("\\(\w+\\)\\(?=\s*=\\)" . font-lock-variable-name-face)
 ("\b\\(\w+\\)\b=" . font-lock-variable-name-face)
```

There is nothing wrong with the elisp code. When I try a more simple regex it works.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Technically, your second regexp should've worked. Even simpler: `"\\w+="` would have worked (but it would also capture the equals sign. Your first regexp doesn't work because Emacs regexp doesn't implement non-capturing groups, other than that, it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

After lots of trial and error I discovered what was wrong.
I just needed to escape twice the 'w' letter
Here is the final line:

```
 ("\\b\\(\\w+\\)\\b=" . font-lock-variable-name-face)
```

Looks easy now :-)